# Sharepoint High Trust App with additional STS Certificate

Tags: sharepoint, certificate

I have a console application that authenticates via 'high trust' (GetS2SAccessTokenWithWindowsIdentity) to a SharePoint.
 This is working fine as long as I'm using the Sharepoint STS Signing Certificate that is preinstalled. You can get it via power shell command: (Get-SPSecurityTokenServiceConfig).LocalLoginProvider.

Now i want to use a self-signed certificate.. Is it possible to add another certificate for the STS (maybe an additional local login provider?). I know it's possible to change the certificate (you have to do it when creating trust with ACS e.g.), but i want an additional one so i can remove it when the application doesn't need it anymore..